# Instagram Authorization URL Has No Cancel Option

Tags: instagram

We're writing a Windows 10 application that has integration with Instagram, and when directing the user to https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token, there isn't a cancel button for the user when presented with the authentication dialog. This proves problematic when running in tablet mode, as Microsoft hides the header bar of the WebAuthenticationBroker dialog containing the "X" to cancel out of it. Is there a URL we could use (or perhaps a query param) that would render a cancel button of sorts that would redirect to the callback URL?